# How to Write auth()->user()->posts()->create($data); in laravel 8 or greater

Tags: laravel

I stuck at auth()->user()->posts()->create($data) line as laravel is not working no it and I do not the alternative way to write this.

Comment: Please tell us more details about your problem.

Comment: what is inside your data property.?

Answer (score -1):

```
posts()->create($data)
```

"posts" should be a relation method of the model "posts". Those methods usualy return a relationship-query, not the result of that query.

If you want to create mutliple "posts" at once just use the model itself like

`App\Models\Post::insert([ [ "name" => "nameItemOne"], [ "name" => "nameItemTwo"]]);`

or for one item

`$createdPostObject = App\Models\Post::create(["name" => "nameItemOne"]);`

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models